# Whats the angular way of autodirecting incomplete url's?

Tags: redirect, angularjs

when i want to get to

```
http://www.koran-auf-deutsch.de/koran-deutsch/23-die-glaubigen-al-mominun/
```

and just enter

```
http://www.koran-auf-deutsch.de/koran-deutsch/23
```

i get directly to the url. i would like to get a similar behaviour
in my angular app, where would you inject that functionality? any ideas?

Comment: Wouldn't this be handled on the API/server side where the data is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
angular.module('app', []).
  config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.
      when('/:id', {controller: RedirectCtrl}).
      when('/:id/:title', {templateUrl: 'partials/post.html', controller: PostCtrl}).
      otherwise({redirectTo: '/404'});
}]);

function RedirectCtrl($routeParam, $http) {

    var post_id = $routeParams.id;

    // get title by id
    $http.get('/api_url_to_get_title_by_id').success(function (data) {
        window.location = "/" + post_id + "/" + data.title;
    });
}

RedirectCtrl.$inject = ['$routeParams', '$http'];
```

Comment: Nice solution! Altough I think post_id needs to be set using $routeParams.id and not $scope.id?